# SQL Server Remote Connection enable for specified IP Address

Tags: sql-server, firewall, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016. In this server I have a SQL Server 2016 installed.

I must configure the sql server to allow remote connections because there are some databeses which synchronise with our local databases.

I do this by openning the SQL Server Configuration Manager, selecting SQL Server Network Configuration and enabling the TCP/IP protocol.

But, this causes a security gap.
I realised that the SQL Log File C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log is constantly increaising the size.

By analysing the log file, I realised that there are some IP addresses tries to connect constantly with a wrong password (15 times per minute).

As I need to keep open the TCP/IP protocol, I tried to add an inbound firewall rule to the firewall but it doesn't change anything.

First, I tried to disable the TCP/IP and authorise connections from a defined IP. It didn't work.
Then, I tried to enable TCP/IP and block the port 1433 for any IP but it doesn't block. I can connect from a local pc.

Briefly, if I enable the TCP/IP, the remote connection is enabled to any IP. If I disable the TCP/IP, the remote connection is disabled to any IP. It doesn't consider the firewall rule.

Is there a way to enable the remote connection for a specific IP Address ?

Here is what I do to block the 1433 port (But I am allways able to connect via SSMS from a local computer ( which is in another domain ) :

[image]

Comment: If you disable TCP/IP then yes, no connections will be able to be made at all. It sounds like you didn't get up your Firewall Rules correctly. Normally you would either have the firewall on, which automatically denies any external connections and only allows those in  the allow list, or you create an ALLOW rule, for the specific IPs and then a DENY rule for **all** IPs lower in the priority; therefore a valid IP would be allow to connect as it passed a rule before hi the DENY. It would be further showing what settings you set in your Firewall rules, as that's where the set up is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will post what I do in FireWall. So I must enable the TCP/IP and add an inbound rule to accept only specified addresses, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced recently the same issue and fixed it by setting customised rule in windows Firewall:

1) Enable TCPIP, otherwise no connection will be possible

2) then you should use the windows firewall as follows:

- first Block the port 1433 for any inbound connection
- then add a customised rule to port 1433 for which you authorise connections from only specific Ip address, you can follow the steps [explained in this link](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2984/How-to-configure-the-Windows-Firewall-to-allow-only-specific-IP-Address-to-connect-your-ports.html)

Here is a screenshot of the firewall setting I have

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the port blocking setting I have

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the firewall rule doesn't work. I posted what I do for blocking the port 1433. Any idea ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the firewall setting I have

Comment: Kemal, the problem is that I can not block the port 1433. I think what you added is to outhorise the an IP address. Do you have a rule to block the port ? I shared the image to show how I do. But it doesn't work.

Comment: There are two ways which I tried and which gave good result: 1- block the 1433 port 2- or remove any rule related to 1433: both allow to block the access to sql from remote domain. and then of course add the customised rule for a specific IP

Comment: I should restart a service maybe ? Because, in my server, it doesn't block at all.

Comment: I added a screenshot of port blocking

Comment: Yes absolutley, you should restart sql service

Comment: It is weird. It doesn't work. I did not try to allow any IP. I try just to block the port but I am able to connect from my local pc.

Comment: On the SQL Server configuration manager, there is a parameter named ListenAll. It is set to Yes. Can it be the problem ?

Comment: here is an explanation of listenall sql server setting https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/support_sql_france/2015/10/09/sql-servers-spn-autoregistration-and-listenall-ip-setting/